# How can i get up to 7 significant figures of my result in FORTRAN90?

Tags: fortran90, significant-digits

```
INTEGER, PARAMETER :: SINGLE=SELECTED_REAL_KIND(7)
REAL(KIND=SINGLE) :: K
REAL::X
...
K=X
WRITE(*,*) K
```

When i write 5 or 6 inside `SELECTED_REAL_KIND`, it outputs six significant figures but when i try 7, it outputs more than 7. Can you tell me why? Where i got it wrong? Assigning is problematic?

With 5 and 6  output-> 1.39256

With 7  output-> 1.3925623893

Okey I'm asking a simple question. How can i just output 7 significant digits of this number  1.3925623893
?

Comment: it would be helpful to show the outputs you get

Comment: It would also help to see what value was originally assigned to either x and/or k. The value of 1.3925623893 means nothing to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From gfortran's documentation:

> SELECTED_REAL_KIND(P,R) returns the kind value of a real data type with decimal precision of at least P digits

The *at least* is important. Floating point numbers are most of the time stored using 4 bytes (single precision) or 8 bytes (double precision) and that's it. That's going from asking 6 to 7 significant figures actually adds even more figures: you switched from single to double precision.

What you really want is have a real large enough to store the precision you want, and you already did that correctly, then *display* only 7 significant figures using a format like:

```
write(*,'(F12.7)') K
```